# Read metadata of a very large .7z file (>50GB)

Tags: r, archive, 7zip

I'm using archive package to read metadata of a very large .7z file. But with archive() function in Rstudio, the result show that the .7z file have no contents in it. But it actually contains about 50GB worth of files.

I tested on smaller size file and it work perfectly fine.

```
# A tibble: 19 x 3
   path                   size      date               
   <chr>                  <int>     <dttm>             
 1 a/                     0         2022-11-30 07:37:18
 2 a/                     0         2022-11-30 07:37:18
 3 a/m.p                  687       2021-02-09 01:40:28
 4 a/t.zip                7681      2021-02-09 01:40:28
```

So, I'm looking for a solution to get the archive() work on the large file.

Answer (score 0):

you didnt say what package is `archive()` from?
you could try zip_list() from https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/zip/

Comment: I'm using archive packpage ([CRAN: archive](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/archive/index.html)) for the main reason that it's the only package I found compatible with .7z format so far.

Comment: If you found a bug; please raise an issue/bug report  (https://github.com/r-lib/archive/issues)

Comment: beyond that; you should see if command line utilities for 7z report the metadata correctly. You can probably drive a command line system call from R if that works.